# Does DB2 JDBC implementation have problems with subselect optimization?

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, websphere

?We have a web app running a query using JDBC with the DB2 Universal JDBC Driver (v9.7).
The query is taking at least 2 minutes to complete when run via the application.
At the command line, however, the same query takes only two seconds.  We can't figure out where the problem lies.

The WebSphere AppServer sits behind a WebSEAL proxy server which has a timeout of 2 minutes, so when the app takes more than 2 minutes to respond, the users see an error.  Users just recently reported the problem, but no recent changes have been made.  I suspect the query response time has been gradually growing and finally reached the WebSEAL timeout.

The query has a subselect in the WHERE clause (which only needs to be run once), and I am wondering if that subselect isn't optimized when going through JDBC, causing it to be re-run with each line of the joined tables.

The query is:

```
SELECT A.VOIDED, A. DELIVERY_DATE_TEXT, A.TRANSACTION_ID, A.AIRBILL_NUMBER, A.NAME, B.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, B.STATUS 
FROM SHIPPING A, TRANSACTION B 
WHERE A.TRANSACTION_ID = B.TRANSACTION_ID 
  AND A.ORIGINAL_REQUEST_TIME < 
     (SELECT ORIGINAL_REQUEST_TIME FROM SHIPPING WHERE AIRBILL_NUMBER = ?) 
  AND B.STATUS <> 4 
  AND A.VOIDED IS NULL
```

The TRANSACTION table has 1.8 million records in it, and the SHIPPING table has 95000.

Is there something wrong with the query?  It works fine at the CLI.
Or is there a bug in the DB2 JDBC driver?

---

Update:

Well, we tried a command-line test program (no Websphere) with a direct connection (rather than a connection pool) and no Spring JDBC wrapper object (which we use in the app), and the problem couldn't be recreated.

Then we used db2expln to examine the query plans for the query with and without the parameter and they were the same either way.

FINALLY, we got around to trying **runstats** on the production table, and that made a difference.  The application query comes back in a *few seconds* now.  The fact that it helped was unexpected.  We hadn't done it originally since the CL query was so fast.

So I guess the problem is **solved**.  But we still don't know why the Websphere JDBC query was originally so much slower than the command line query (and the non-Websphere JDBC query).

Comment: Chances are that JDBC is not the issue here, but rather that there is some other difference.  Are you sure that the web application is providing actual values for AIRBILL_NUMBER and STATUS, or is it using parameter markers?

Comment: "B.STATUS <> 4" is hardcoded in the query.  The AIRBILL_NUMBER is the only parameter.  The query is working: sometimes a response will be returned in just under the timeout value and the return data is correct, but that is rare, and it still takes way too long.  The same code works fine in our test environment, but the table size is much smaller.  This query and associated code has been working for years, and I suspect a combination of the table size and JDBC driver version is responsible for the slow response we are seeing now.

Comment: You may want to compare the query plans generated for the query: one with the parameter marker and the other with the literal. Try to update statistics on the `SHIPPING` table with distribution.

Comment: Problem solved with runstats.  See update above.

Comment: Colleague found this which seems the same or very similar: http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1688344-compiler-using-different-runstats-prepared-direct-statement.html

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the difference in this case is that the JDBC query submitted is using a parameter marker, whereas the query you are running on the command line has all values shown explicitly.

With a the explicit value, DB2 is able to utilize distribution statistics to compile the query, which is likely resulting in a more effective query plan.  As @mustaccio suggests, you should compare the query plans between the 2 variants of the query to see what DB2 is doing differently between them.

Comment: The estimated cost value (44770) and query plan graph (returned from db2expln) is the same with and without the parameter marker.